# MSQL get first 100 rows of not intersection

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I have 2 tables in MSQL

The first one is called **tbl_file** and it has the following properties:

- id
- hash_id
- description
- mime-type
- creation date
- etc..

The second one is called **tbl_sys_filecontent** and it only has:

- id
- content (base64)

It's supposed that these two tables must have the same row size. (***hash-id*** of **tbl_file** is the same as ***id*** in **tbl_sys_filecontent**

However, something went wrong and now if we execute:

```
select count(*) from tbl_sys_filecontent;
```

We get about 1 000 000 rows

And we're supposed to get the same row count after executing the query:

```
select count(*) from tbl_file as f
JOIN tbl_sys_filecontent as sf on f.hash_id = sf.id;
```

But we are returned with only roughly 100 000 results

Let's call the first query collection **A** and the second **B**

The question is how do I get the first 100 rows which are equal to **A-B** (so the hashes aren't equal?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *not exists*

```
select *
from tbl_file as f
where not exists (select 'x' from tbl_sys_filecontent  as sf where f.hash_id = sf.id);
```

With *not in*

```
select *
from tbl_file as f
where f.hash_id not in (select 'x' from tbl_sys_filecontent  as sf);
```

However, *not exists* is to favor over *not in*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11074428/59119

With a *left join*

```
select f.* from tbl_file as f
    LEFT JOIN tbl_sys_filecontent as sf on f.hash_id = sf.id
where sf.id is null;
```

Comment: Hmmm. I'm sorry, perhaps didn't ask the question correctly. I need to get from the table `tbl_sys_filecontent` the rows which aren't present in the **B** query

Comment: So, I should get about 900 000 rows

Comment: @Joe Doe take my examples, but switch the tables. That should do it.